# Join Erroring on Value That Doesn't Exist

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am finding that a subquery that is built to return some specific IDs does not work within a join condition as I would expect. However if I use the same subquery to build a table full of those values, and use it in the same join clause, the query is a success.

It feels as is Snowflake is scanning the source table of the subquery and erroring out on a value, even though that value isn't actually in the result set of the subquery.

See code example below:

```
create table CompanyAssetExternalIDs_TEMP as 
    select distinct to_number(external_id,38,0) as external_id
    from "Company_assets_ev"
    where provider = 'screenplay'
    and external_id is not null
    and external_id != ''
    and external_id != 'NULL'
        
// This query doesn't work, it fails on "Numeric value '6162211ca2d88b37ac48dc0d' is not recognized" however that value doesn't exist in the subquery, nor in the main select table
select
last_day(LA.created_at::date,'month') Month,
LA.rights_holder
from "linear_asset" LA
//This sub query is the same SQL as the create table command above so we can be sure they only contain the same values
inner join 
(
    select distinct to_number(external_id,38,0) as external_id
    from "Company_assets_ev"
    where provider = 'screenplay'
    and external_id is not null
    and external_id != ''
    and external_id != 'NULL'
) SubQueryJoin on SubQueryJoin.external_id = LA.External_id

//This query works, despite the fact that its joined on, what should be, the exact same set of data as the subquery above
select
last_day(LA.created_at::date,'month') Month,
LA.rights_holder
from "linear_asset" LA
inner join "Company_DW"."PUBLIC"."CompanyAssetExternalIDs_TEMP" as TableJoin on TableJoin.external_id = LA.external_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `try_to_number` to nullify non-number values:

```
select last_day(LA.created_at::date,'month') Month,
       LA.rights_holder
from "linear_asset" LA
inner join 
(
    select distinct try_to_number(external_id,38,0) as external_id
    from "Company_assets_ev"
    where provider = 'screenplay'
    and external_id is not null
    and external_id != ''
    and external_id != 'NULL'
) SubQueryJoin on SubQueryJoin.external_id = LA.External_id
```

Comment: Thats it! I have no idea why though but I'll check out some documentation on try_to_number. Will mark as the answer in ten minutes. 

If you have any other info about why this works please pass it along, I'd love to know.

Comment: @MPJ567 Even if the values are filtered out in subquery, please note that subquery is not fenced, meaning query optimizer could rewrite it at its own discretion(like predicate pushdown). It is the reason why version with materialized table works.